# Calling the same function on eterogene MdiChild FormVB.NET

Tags: vb.net, mdichild

I have a list of eterogene MDIChildForms (MyChild1, MyChild2, ...) in my MDIParent. All of this form have a public function myFunction(p As myType). I would like to loop them and for each one call myFunction.

Pseudocode:

```
For Each myChild In Me.MdiChildren
     myChild.myFuntion(p)
Next
```

Is it possible? How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define an interface that declares that method and then implement that interface in each child form class.

```vb
Public Interface ISomeInterface

    Sub SomeMethod()

End Interface
```

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Implements ISomeInterface

    Public Sub SomeMethod() Implements ISomeInterface.SomeMethod
        '...
    End Sub

End Class
```

You can then cast each form as that type and call the method, e.g.

```vb
For Each mdiChild As ISomeInterface In MdiChildren
    mdiChild.SomeMethod()
Next
```

That assumes that every form implements that interface. If some don't, you can do this:

```vb
For Each mdiChild In MdiChildren.OfType(Of ISomeInterface)()
    mdiChild.SomeMethod()
Next
```